# create db2 schema using jdbc

Tags: sql, database, jdbc, db2, database-schema

What is the correct syntax or what are the correct steps for **creating a schema in DB2 using JDBC**?

When running `create schema test1` or `create schema test1 authorization db2admin` as db2admin, I consistently get `DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-552, SQLSTATE=42502, SQLERRMC=DB2ADMIN;CREATE SCHEMA, DRIVER=3.64.106`

The exact same command works fine using the DB2 command-line tools.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found it.

It turns out that for some reason DB2 Express-C does not grant the DBADM privilege to db2admin by default.

This can be fixed by connecting to the DB and then issuing

```
GRANT DBADM ON DATABASE to db2admin
```

Thanks Ian Bjorhovde for providing the inspiration spark!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is not a matter of Syntax but authentication, you have to check the credentials that you are passing through JDBC:

> -552 authorization-id DOES NOT HAVE THE PRIVILEGE TO PERFORM OPERATION operation

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fn552.htm

Comment: As I said, the user is DB2Admin and has all the rights. This same user can execute the statement with the DB2 command-line tools without problems.

Comment: I would try to narrow down the root cause, can you use another DB2 client and try to perform some DDL with the same credentials? http://java-source.net/open-source/sql-clients

Comment: Already did that. I also tried 3 different versions of the jdbc driver: an older one and the newest jdbc3 and jdbc4 ones. No luck.

Comment: So the next steps would be to try the same code against a fresh DB server and see what happens, it might give you some clues: http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express-c/download.html

Comment: Already did that. Have Express-C running (latest version) and tried against a fresh instance.

Comment: Got the same result? Is it just for the "create schema" operation? How about some "alter table"? Did you try something else like Hibernate or Apache Ddlutils http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/ ?

Comment: Well, it must be a bug then; e.g., http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IZ80983. Did you try to create a new DB with a different user and run the same code with these new credentials?

Comment: Please post the results of the query `select dbadmauth from syscat.dbauth where grantee = current user` when you are connected to the database as the user that is trying to execute `CREATE SCHEMA`