# How to create a new schema on a database at IBM Data Studio?

Tags: database, db2, ibm-data-studio

I am trying to create a new schema on a database that I created at IBM Data Studio but I get error:

> "DB2ADMIN" does not have the privilege to perform operation "CREATE SCHEMA".. SQLCODE=-552, SQLSTATE=42502, DRIVER=3.67.28.

How can I do it on command line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is just because the user that you are using to connect to the database does not have the DBADM authority.

Possible duplicate of this question: [create db2 schema using jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992987/create-db2-schema-using-jdbc)

Please check the documentation: [create db2 schema using jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992987/create-db2-schema-using-jdbc)